# How can i set the flags with gentoo prefix

Tags: linux, bash, gentoo

I have install the [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) system , after that I tried to install the gentoo prefix on my system. But it comes error:

```
I'm going to check for some variables in your environment now:  
  it appears ASFLAGS is not set :)  
  it appears CFLAGS is not set :)  
  it appears CPPFLAGS is not set :)   
  it appears CXXFLAGS is not set :)  
  it appears DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set :)  
  it appears GREP_OPTIONS is not set :)  
  it appears LDFLAGS is not set :)  
  it appears LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set :)  
  it appears LIBPATH is not set :)  
  it appears PERL_MM_OPT is not set :)  
  uh oh, PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/kde/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/kde/share  /pkgconfig:/opt/qt/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/share/pkgconfig :(  

Ahem, your shell environment contains some variables I'm allergic to:  
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH  
These flags can and will influence the way in which packages compile.  
In fact, they have a long standing tradition to break things.  I really  
prefer to be on my own here.  So please make sure you disable these  
environment variables in your shell initialisation files.  After you've  
done that, you can run me again.
```

How can i set these environment variables? I tried to echo these flags on my gentoo, but it output nothing.

Comment: `unset PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

Comment: Sorry for replied you so later. I tried `unset PKG_CONFIG_PATH`,and run the `bootrstrap-prefix.sh` script again. It comes the same error.

Comment: Add `unset PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to your ~/.profile file.

Answer (score 1):

The first ones are alright, it checks if they are unset. The last one, you can just do `unset PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. You may opt to install Gentoo Linux itself if you come across more problems, it is lightweight enough compared to LFS and you can always try to trim it down if you feel it is not.